# Log nothing with DDASLLogger in IOS7 on a real device

Tags: ios, logging

Using [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) in IOS7 on an ipod5, I Added a DDASLLogger to DDLog, and logged something. And used "asl_search" to get logs, but got nothing. When I did it on ios7 iphone simulator, I got what I exactly logged. Is it a bug of DDASLLogger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer just now: YES. It's a bug recording to "[asl_search only finds messages with ReadUID set](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/09/welcome-to-ios-7-issues/)". We need to set the ReadUID property for a message when sending it to ASL. Otherwise asl_search cannot find it.

The code of sending message in DDASLLogger is as following:

```
- (void)logMessage:(DDLogMessage *)logMessage
{
    NSString *logMsg = logMessage->logMsg;

    if (formatter)
    {
        logMsg = [formatter formatLogMessage:logMessage];
    }

    if (logMsg)
    {
        const char *msg = [logMsg UTF8String];

        int aslLogLevel;
        switch (logMessage->logFlag)
        {
            // Note: By default ASL will filter anything above level 5 (Notice).
            // So our mappings shouldn't go above that level.

            case LOG_FLAG_ERROR : aslLogLevel = ASL_LEVEL_ALERT;   break;
            case LOG_FLAG_WARN  : aslLogLevel = ASL_LEVEL_CRIT;    break;
            case LOG_FLAG_INFO  : aslLogLevel = ASL_LEVEL_ERR;     break;
            case LOG_FLAG_DEBUG : aslLogLevel = ASL_LEVEL_WARNING; break;
            default             : aslLogLevel = ASL_LEVEL_NOTICE;  break;
        }

        asl_log(client, NULL, aslLogLevel, "%s", msg);
    }
}
```

We just need to change

```
        asl_log(client, NULL, aslLogLevel, "%s", msg);
```

to

```
        aslmsg m = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_MSG);
        asl_set(m, ASL_KEY_READ_UID, "501");
        asl_log(client, m, aslLogLevel, "%s", msg);
```

It works. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer and the problem is still happening in iOS 7.1. Worse still, ASL_KEY_READ_UID appears to be completely undocumented.

Comment: I have made a pull request on github last week. So the latest version doesn't have this issue.